# Evaluate $\int\frac{\cos(5x) + \cos(4x)}{1-2\cos(3x)}dx$

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I need help evaluating the indefinite integral $$\int\frac{\cos(5x) + \cos(4x)}{1-2\cos(3x)}dx.$$

Comment: What efforts did you make to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried converting 5x into 3x + 2x, but made no progress. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Set $x=2y$ and

use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)  and $\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A$

$$\dfrac{\cos10y+\cos8y}{1-2\cos6y}=\dfrac{2\cos9y\cos y}{1-2(2\cos^23y-1)}$$

$$=\dfrac{2\cos y(4\cos^33y-3\cos3y)}{-(4\cos^23y-3)}$$

$$=-2\cos y\cos3y=-[\cos(3y-y)+\cos(3y+y)]$$

Comment: The last formula is known as http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html